# Как добавить карточку с нужным текстом?

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, что здесь не правильно?

```
 if (data == null){
        return;
    } String name = data.getStringExtra("name");
    adapter = new RecycleAdapter(listItems, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    listItems.add(new RecyclerItem(name, "top"));
```

(пользователь на одном активити нажимает кнопку, его перекидывает на другое активити, где он вводит текст, и этот текст  на карточке, которая создается на первом актирити)

Comment: Опишите вопрос более подробно. Что Вы пытаетесь сделать ? Какие карточки куда добавить ?

Comment: я пытаюсь сделать, чтобы в приложении при нажатии на кнопку создавался элемент cardview с нужным текстом

Comment: А зачем Вам onActivityResult() ? Этот кардвью Вы в список размещаете или где ?

Comment: через onActivityResult() я получаю текст, который должен являться названием карточки

Comment: колбэк `onActivityResult()` вызывается при возврате значения из текущего активити в ранее вызванное активити . Каким образом это относится к вашему вопросу? Опишите свою проблему так, чтобы у людей, с ней не знакомых, не возникало уточняющих вопросов. Приложите код, связанный с проблемой. Как здесь [задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы получить полезный ответ

Comment: надо чтобы пользователь на одном активити нажимал  кнопку, его перекидывало на другое активити, где он вводил текст, и этот текст был на карточке, которая создавалась на первом актирити